# How to mock angular/node third-party modules with jest

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am trying to mock the whole **ng-inline-svg** module (which is a third-party angular module).

I have tried putting the following code into my jest global mocks file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

const ngInlineSvgBaseMock = jest.genMockFromModule('ng-inline-svg');

@NgModule()
class NgInlineSvgMockModule {
  public static forRoot = jest.fn();
}

ngInlineSvgBaseMock['InlineSVGModule'] = NgInlineSvgMockModule;

module.exports = ngInlineSvgBaseMock;
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token


    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

 

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:

     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.

     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.

     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:

    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    C:\git2\xxx-ui\node_modules\ng-inline-svg\lib\index.js:1

    export { InlineSVGConfig } from './inline-svg.config';

    ^^^^^^     

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

       9 |   public static forRoot = jest.fn();

      10 | }

    > 11 |

         | ^

      12 | ngInlineSvgBaseMock['InlineSVGModule'] = NgInlineSvgMockModule;

      13 |

      14 | module.exports = ngInlineSvgBaseMock;

      at Runtime._execModule (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1179:56)

      at Object.<anonymous> (jest-globals.ts:11:32)
```

Can someone please help and provide tips as to how to use jest in order to mock whole third-party modules?

Comment: It's the same problem as you posted previously. I assume jest.genMockFromModule tries to evaluate the module and fails because of syntax error because `export` isn't allowed in Node CommonJS modules. Try jest.mock instead.

Comment: Can you post sample code please? I have tried replacing `jest.genMockFromModule(` with `jest.mock(` to no avail. I am not sure how to use this feature of jest...

Comment: I can't test it right now but I'd expect something like `jest.mock('ng-inline-svg', () => { let mockModule = new NgModule({}); mockModule.forRoot = jest.fn().mockReturnThis(); return { __esModule: true, InlineSVGModule: mockModule })`. Or you can stick to global mock module like you already did (it's `__mock__/ng-inline-svg.ts`, I guess), just skip `ngInlineSvgBaseMock` and export a dummy module with dummy `inlineSVG` directive  from there, `module.exports = { __esModule: true, InlineSVGModule: NgInlineSvgMockModule }`.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I am going to try it out and will let you know. :-)

Comment: I have used a global mock file where I have put all my mocked modules. Thanks again!